# Get active time for device

Tags: android

How can I count active time for device?
It's a time when device not sleeping(when the screen is ON).
**SystemClock.uptimeMillis()** not suitable because it does not count only the time for deep sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For screen on-off state, you can try with ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intents, as shown in this blog post: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/